# c# build folders in app.path from listbox strings

Tags: c#

am new to this language so take it, easy guys, I am mainly user of vb6
I have Listbox1 and it has 3 strings for the test.
demo
love
codes

```
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(textBox1.Text);

        for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // do with listBox1.Items[i]

            /// listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(textBox1.Text + listBox1.Items[i]);
        }



    }
}
```

this works now how do i check if it exists before it does this

app.path  has **database** folder
folder structure will be like this
database\love
databae\codes
database\demo
so on click check if database folder exist if not create it then loop listbox1 and create all them to if they do not exist.

Comment: System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory will simply do nothing if directory already exists so this code is safe. If you need to check there is System.IO.Directory.Exists() method.

Comment: Thanks buddy. May i know why i got minus on post before as i stated am still new on this language

Comment: how do i clear textbox2.text on double click